# Texture Painting Duplication and Inverted

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm once again asking for your help. When I paint in Texture Painting, it makes unwanted duplications and for some reason, it comes out inverted. Please help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to redo your UV map. Make sure you have appropriate seams marked, and unwrap the mesh. Then go to the UV editor and arrange the UV islands so that none of them overlap, and rotate them so all the bricks line up horizontally. Watching a quick tutorial will help, the language can be confusing at first but it is an intuitive process once you see it demonstrated. Search for "UV mapping" or "UV islands"

The duplicates can happen if you edit a mesh after unwrapping it, because new areas of mesh have to double up on the existing UV map. Similar to drawing in sharpie on a folded newspaper, anything beneath the sharpie will be marked, not just the top layer.